# Setting attribute value in constructor from Ionic 2 storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a service where I retrieve data from my server, and I send over a token in my POST data. Problem is, the token is stored in local storage and I try to assign it to my token attribute in my service class, but it simply doesn't work (no errors or anything). Here's what my code looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import  { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyData {
    http: any;
    baseUrl: String;
    token: String;

    constructor(
        http: Http,
        public storage: Storage){
            this.http = http;
            this.baseUrl = 'http://192.168.0.109:8000';
            this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
                this.token = value;
            });
    }

    getTickets(){
        console.log(this.token); // Doesn't show the token, I know it's in storage I have verified through other means
    }
}
```

I call `getTickets()` as follows from one of my page ts files:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyData } from '../../providers/my-data';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-account',
  templateUrl: 'account.html',
})
export class AccountPage {
  token: String;
  events: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public myData: MyData,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public storage: Storage) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.myData.getTickets().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Comment: where are you calling this method `getTickets()`

Comment: @Aravind From the `ionViewDidLoad()` function of one of my pages

Comment: how you are calling? update that to post

Comment: @Aravind Okay, done - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct and the value will also come, the only problem here  is getTickets() method is being called before any value is assigned to token.

So pass the token value from AccountPage. and this will sove the problem.